# How to get Geo data through Internet?

Tags: java, android, android-location

In an android app, I have written code to get geo data through GPS or Network, which one is enable get the data through that. Here is my code,

```
public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
{
    boolean gps_enabled=false;
    LocationManager lm;
    boolean network_enabled=false; 
    this.context = context;
    locationResult=result;
    Toast.makeText( context,"getLocation()",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(lm == null)
        lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try
    {
        gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}

    try
    {
        network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}


    if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "GPS & Network disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Using `LocationManager` check whether GPS & NetWork is on or not.

If GPS is in ON, in boolean value gps_enabled assigned "true".

But in network, I have activated 2G Internet access in HTC desire android device, and Switched ON in Mobile network.

The boolean variable `network_enabled` assigned to "false" even network in On state.

Are we want to change in settings anything in device? or any mistake in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on availability:

```
Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
if(gps_enabled)
gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
if(network_enabled)
net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

**NETWORK_PROVIDER:** Name of the network location provider. This provider determines location based on availability of cell tower and WiFi access points. Results are retrieved by means of a network lookup. Requires either of the permissions android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

**GPS_PROVIDER :** Name of the GPS location provider. This provider determines location using satellites. Depending on conditions, this provider may take a while to return a location fix. Requires the permission android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

See this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getBestProvider%28android.location.Criteria,%20boolean%29

Comment: That is not the issue i have used this code, When i debug the code, the variable assigned network_enabled= false, but i have ON the mobile network. why?

Comment: You mean, if you set network_enabled=false..but still the symbol of network WiFi on your device shows as ON??

Comment: No. I have switched on the nework in device, but in variable showed network_enabled = false at debug time and data is not availabled through network. That is my issue.